# How do I pick nice random colors when drawing a chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, colors

I need to get some random colors to draw a pie. My code works but it can take the same color again and again

```
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 255;
        int rand1 = r.Next(min, max);
        int rand2 = r.Next(min, max);
        int rand3 = r.Next(min, max);
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(rand1, rand2, rand3);  
        //drawing the pie here
   }
```

How can I rework it so that it's not going to pick the same color again.

Comment: is this Java? please tag properly.

Comment: maybe the random generator needs a seed number, e.g. timestamp

Comment: its C# in asp.net and i have tryed to set a seed number didnt help

Comment: Regarding a proper `Random`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/768001/90674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the random colors you generate in a container, then check if **a similar color by a certain delta** has already been inserted in the container.

This way you won't risk to pick up a different color but very similar, like:
`RGB(0, 0, 0)` and `RGB(10, 2, 3)`

```
const int DELTA_PERCENT = 10;
List<Color> alreadyChoosenColors = new List<Color>();

// initialize the random generator
Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    bool chooseAnotherColor = true;      
    while ( chooseAnotherColor )
    {
       // create a random color by generating three random channels
       //
       int redColor = r.Next(0, 255);
       int greenColor = r.Next(0, 255);
       int blueColor = r.Next(0, 255);
       Color tmpColor = Color.FromArgb(redColor, greenColor, blueColor);  

       // check if a similar color has already been created
       //
       chooseAnotherColor = false;
       foreach (Color c in alreadyChoosenColors)
       {
          int delta = c.R * DELTA_PERCENT / 100;
          if ( c.R-delta <= tmpColor.R && tmpColor.R <= c.R+delta )
          {
             chooseAnotherColor = true;
             break;
          }

          delta = c.G * DELTA_PERCENT / 100;
          if ( c.G-delta <= tmpColor.G && tmpColor.G <= c.G+delta )
          {
             chooseAnotherColor = true;
             break;
          }

          delta = c.B * DELTA_PERCENT / 100;
          if ( c.B-delta <= tmpColor.B && tmpColor.B <= c.B+delta )
          {
             chooseAnotherColor = true;
             break;
          }
        }
    }

    alreadyChoosenColors.Add(tmpColor);
    // you can safely use the tmpColor here

   }
```

Comment: i cant get 
List<Color> alreadyChoosenColors = new ArrayList<Color>();
 to work

Answer (score 3):

It’s usually a better idea to create some nice palette beforehand and then pick the colors from the palette. In pseudocode:

```
var Palette = new Array(Color(r1, g1, b1), Color(r2, g2, b2), …);
for (var i=0; i<numberOfPieSegments; i++)
    drawPieSegment(Palette[i % Palette.length], …);
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but some times the amount of colors if big and manually create it require times that a random generator spare us

Answer (score -2):

see msdn for [descripton of Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.random.aspx), check this: **However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.** 
For this reason, you should use a different seed to initialize Random instance each time. I recommend the timestamp.

Comment: This is not what's happening here. The OP's constructing only one instance of `Random` and using it. OP's probably picking similar  colors (looking equal even if the numbers are different).